# Adjust Columns width/size in Product Grid in Magento Admin

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, column, product-grid

I just wonder why the size/width in Product Grid in the admin panel is not adjusting. I created a local copy of the grid.php from the core file. I tried editing the sizes of the column `(/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php)` but when I try to refresh the admin page nothing happens. I cleared the cache still the same the width are the same.

Can anyone guide me how to increase the width size of every column?

EDIT:
In addition, is there a way I can the FROM and TO in the PRICE and QTY Column? How?

Comment: Have you added such column to grid collection?

Comment: there is a 'width' => '70px', option for each column  in _prepareColumns() function  of grid.php

Comment: Yes, I tried that one as mentioned above but it's not working

Comment: It works fine for me. check after clearing cache

Comment: It should be. I tried clearing all cache and even flushed it but to no avail

Comment: check if grid.php is rewrite by any other custom extensions

Comment: Rewrite? how do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you remove `'type'  => 'number'` from the array then you will be able to change the width.

Comment: I have faced same problem, when I remove 'type', I am able adjust the width, else not. I can't find logic behind it

Answer (score 3):

Try the below,

In `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

Under `_prepareColumns()` function,

```
 $this->addColumn('entity_id',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type'  => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
        ));
```

By changing this `'width' => '50px',`the column width can be changed

Comment: With the help of width you can set the width of column, you can change as per your requirements.

Comment: The way I understand it first, yes I'll just have to adjust the width of every column in _prepareColumns() but the thing is, it's not working. So I was thinking that maybe there's still a different file that needed to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

For those `'width' => '{number}px',` is not working as intended, if you have a hidden column, the width change will take place x column(s) earlier.

For example, if you have columns as follows, you will have to place `'width' => '25px'` in the column2 in order to change the width of column3

```
$this->addColumn('hidden_column1', array('header' => 'hidden_column1', 'column_css_class'=>'no-display', 'header_css_class'=>'no-display'));
$this->addColumn('column2',
        array(
            'header' => 'column2',
            'width' => '25px', //here
        ));
$this->addColumn('column3',
        array(
            'header' => 'column3',
             //not here
        ));
```