# Magento 2 : Change Admin grid column width

Tags: magento2, grid, column

I have added an admin grid using UI component in my custom module. Now I want to change the column width of admin grid.

This is the code that I am using for adding column in admin grid :

```
 <column name="product_title">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

**Please Help me**

Comment: Did you check here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76426/adjust-columns-width-size-in-product-grid-in-magento-admin

Answer (score 4):

At the moment on Magento 2.3.2 the only working solution requires adding configuration in 2 peaces in [List (Grid) UI component](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-listing-grid.html):

1. Setup `resizeConfig` for columns config.
2. Setup `resizeDefaultWidth` for specific column.
3. Setup `resizeEnabled` for specific column (optional).

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item><!-- This is required configuration -->
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <column name="column_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item><!-- "true" allows admin user to change column width (default value); "false" - disallows admin user to change column width -->
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="number">100</item><!-- needed column width in pixels -->
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

The answer why this works only in the way I've described is in JS function [initResize](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/listing.js#L127).

Answer (score 1):

it may help just giving you example to use just like in new version of magento used.

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="package">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Design</argument>
                            <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                            <argument name="options" xsi:type="options" model="Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\Label\Options"/>
                            <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">150px</argument>
                            <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">design</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
```

you can look width as argument in xml

```
<argument name="width" xsi:type="string">150px</argument>
```

Also if you have to follow strict ui components you can use [Resize component.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-resize.html)

example from source link

```
<column name="creation_time">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">60</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

hope it will work for you

Comment: This is used for Grid UI component?

Comment: ah, can also used http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-resize.html   resize components

Comment: Still no change in my column width. :-(

Comment: I m also facing same issue.Please help.

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-secondary-resize.html follow this step by step i am sure you will get it done

Comment: yea same issue, not working with UI Component

Comment: Is anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **resizeDefaultWidth** to change column with, required **resizeEnabled** = **false**,

Example code here.

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Search\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\SynonymActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the given answers and no luck.

Then I resolved by adding some css to my output of column data.

```
<column name="detail_info" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\DetailInfo">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Detail Information</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

DetailInfo.php file I wrapped my output to div with some width.

```
$items['detail_info'] = '<div style="300px">'.$items['detail_info'].'</div>';
```